# SELECT problems with Doctrine and MS SQL 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, doctrine-orm, freetds

We have written an application using Doctrine2, which works great when used with a MySQL or Postgres database.

We now connected the application with a SQL Server 2008 database using [PDO Driver DBLib](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) which uses the `FreeTDS` implementation for the TDS (Tabular DataStream protocol), which is shared by SQL Server and Sybase.

The initial schema creation, transactions and `INSERT`s into the tables work fine .. after some tweaking of the Doctrine `SQLServerPlatform` and our MSSQL Driver package.

But when selecting data, we face the following error:

```
General error: 20019 Attempt to initiate a new Adaptive Server operation with results pending
```

After plenty of googling I found [this detail in the FAQ of FreeTDS](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#pending):

> If you are accustomed to programming with other database servers, you may be surprised when you first encounter this aspect of the TDS protocol.  [...]
> The server requires the client either to read all the results from a query, or to indicate that no further rows are desired i.e., to issue a cancellation. Until one of those two things happens, the server will not accept new queries on that connection. It will complain about "pending results".

So the cause for the error message is that for some reason, Doctrine (DBAL->PDO->FreeTDS) did not read all the result rows from the connection buffer, and the server / library doesn't allow the application to issue a new `exec()`/`execute()` until all rows are read.

- Is my understanding right that `$doctrinequery->getResults()` fetches all results before it returns?
- Is my understanding right that `$entity->getLinkedEntity()` (i.e. `$user->getGroupNames()`) fetches all results before it returns?
- How would you tackle down where exactly the problem is? 
  The stacktraces are not helping us at all and the codebase is already grown.
- Did anybody else already have this problem and can share some insights?
- Is there an alternative we can use to connect Doctrine to MSSQL which does not suffer this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problems with PDO Driver DBLib and transactions. I fixed it this way:

```
$this->_db->beginTransaction();

$st = $this->_db->prepare("StoredProcedure ?");
$st->execute(array($data));
$results= $st->fetchAll();
$st->closeCursor();

// more stuff

$this->_db->commit();
```

`closeCursor()` solved my problem: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php